# Access HTML attribute element with variable

Tags: javascript, html

**Setup:**
I have a variable called `tabcontent` containing an HTMLCollection with items called `Drums` and `Animals` inside it. I also have a variable called `activeTabName` that is accessing the innerHTML of whatever tab I currently have open. It can equal either `Drums` or `Animals`. For simplicity I just made it directly equal `Drums`.

```
var activeTabName = "Drums";
console.log(tabcontent.Drums); // Prints Drums portion of HTMLCollection
console.log(tabcontent.activeTabName); // Prints undefined
```

**Question:**
How do I access HTML attributes with my variable `activeTabName`? Also, why is `tabcontent.activeTabName` undefined?

Comment: because you are looking for "activeTabName", it has no clue it is supposed to be a variable.

Comment: Try doing `tabcontent[activeTabName];`

Comment: @ epascarello - So, you're saying instead of `tabcontent.Drums` it's looking for `tabcontent."Drums"`? Is there a way to store Drums without the quotation marks inside a variable?

Comment: Follow the link and learn about bracket notation where you can use the variable.

Comment: or read MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: @Animesh Kumar - That works perfectly, thanks. @ epascarello - Thank you for the link.